# Не работает if/else в PHP при встраивании его в html

Tags: php, html, mysql

Вроде все правильно:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но почему оно игнорит else??. Переменная $errorMessage существует на момент вызова файла. Как будто ему пофиг на встроеный ПХП с условиями...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так может нужно закрыть PHP вставку. И вообще использовать сокращенную записть if else . http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: убедитесь, что вы можете использовать PHP short tags. Закройте php ?>, на скрине не увидал

Comment: Код полностью рабочий http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/efb7a066ed84a1f62083096045af5c16538f7a68

Comment: @Daniil, закрывающий тег php в конце файла мало того что не обязателен, много где советуют именно **не** ставить его.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский его рекомендуют не ставят только если это **целиком** php файл, например *class*.  Вы видите, что тут есть html?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Точка с запятой лишняя. Нужно удалить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ...с чего бы это?

Comment: Вот с того http://php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: Так, и? что там должно было указать на то, что конструкция невалидная?

Answer (score 1):

Используй такие конструкции:

```
if($a > 10):

else:

endif;
```

Comment: Пробовал. Ничего не изменилось.

Comment: @JohnDoe, вам советуют в комментарии использовать `<?php`, а не короткий аналог.